# Link_to in Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use "link_to" in a mailer.rb file. I have already set the default host in an initializer.

Neither of the following includes works

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base

   ...
   "#{ link_to 'something', something_url } is the link"

end
```

Errors I get, when calling `MessageMailer.welcome_employer(Employer.find(18)).deliver` in the console:

(with neither or `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` is present)
NoMethodError: undefined method `link_to' for #

(with only 'include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper' or both present)
RuntimeError: In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Answer (score 2):

I used it in dynamic emailer using view_content as below,

```
@email_type.header.gsub('<Lot_No>',"#{view_context.link_to tile, root_url + product_tile_path(params)}")
```

Comment: `link to` can be accessed through `view_context.link_to`

Answer (score 0):

I have done to solve this issue with 2 ways in rails 4:

1. You can specify your mailer host in each environment. For instance:

   Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'http://localhost:3000'
2. You can use ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to

   ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to("Active", disable_sub_newsletter_users_url, :class => "tiny button alert", method: :post)

or

3. Use url for

   Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(:controller => "users", :action => "disable_sub_newsletter"
4. You have to remove 2 lines above your class

   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

   include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5, the following worked for me:

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  "#{ view_context.link_to 'something', something_url } is the link"

end
```

Answer (score -1):

To make the url helpers availabe in `MessageMailer` you must move the includes into the class definition:

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  "#{ link_to 'something', something_url } is the link"

end
```